# I want to parse GNSS data from NMEA sentence using STM32F0 and Truestudio

Tags: gps, embedded, stm32

I am facing difficulty while parsing GPS data from NMEA sentence. I am using Quectel L89 GNSS module (baud rate: 115200) and Truestudio IDE. I had used CubeMX for making skeletal structure of program.

I had tried using both `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` with `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` and `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` independently. I am able to read data sometimes and sometimes not. The thing is that raw data starts from $GPRMC AND ends with $PSTMCPU while reading data from ST sometimes rec_buffer starts from $GPRMC(ok condition) and sometimes from $GNVTG(wrong condition).

How will I ensure that rec_buffer always starts from $GPRMC

I am calling this in while(1):

```
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, rec_buff, 2400);  // from GPS UART
```

I also tried this:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(   UART_HandleTypeDef *    huart   )
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART2)  //GPS UART
    {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &rec_buff[0], 1, 10);
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, rrc_buff, 2400);   
    }
}
```

**L89 RAW DATA:**

```
$GPRMC,094640.000,A,2838.86700,N,07711.56483,E,0.4,99.3,050119,,,A*5E
$GPGGA,094640.000,2838.86700,N,07711.56483,E,1,08,1.0,226.91,M,-35.9,M,,*42
$GNGNS,094640.000,2838.86700,N,07711.56483,E,ANNNNN,08,1.0,0226.9,-35.9,,*78
$GPVTG,99.3,T,,M,0.4,N,0.7,K,A*3D
$GPGST,094640.000,46.0,26.0,17.7,0.2,25.7,18.2,19.6*68
$GPGBS,094640.000,25.7,18.2,19.6,,,,*4B
$GNGSA,A,3,23,09,03,16,26,22,27,07,,,,,1.9,1.0,1.6*28
$GNGSA,A,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.9,1.0,1.6*22
$GPGSV,3,1,11,16,70,076,27,03,58,227,30,23,52,331,36,26,44,046,18*78
$GPGSV,3,2,11,22,44,198,21,09,24,316,34,27,19,137,19,07,16,266,27*70
$GPGSV,3,3,11,31,14,058,,14,10,112,,08,09,164,20,,,,*45
$PSTMPRES,14.7,-4.3,3.4,4.7,8.1,-34.9,-10.0,14.5,-8.6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*05
$PSTMVRES,0.3,-0.0,0.0,-0.0,0.3,0.0,-0.5,-0.5,0.1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0B
$PSTMTG,2034,553618.0000,8,128199118,10,-46760.0000,002a,1025,0,0,10,2034,553618.0000,10,2034,553618.0000,6*5A
$PSTMTS,1,23,87178102.875,-44634.02,01,36,107871,1,9650745.91,13059080.41,21268551.81,-1601.01,2104.54,-615.14,-60384.66,6.69,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*01
$PSTMTS,1,09,88801609.812,-43889.80,01,34,102805,1,16028885.38,3193585.53,20890300.53,-1492.86,2210.83,804.75,142511.90,11.66,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*07
$PSTMTS,1,03,86575601.125,-48258.84,01,30,78613,1,13348561.56,22507400.16,4720188.47,-3.99,659.00,-3098.78,52480.77,6.38,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*2D
$PSTMTS,1,16,85874269.688,-47283.16,01,27,75521,1,-1886095.16,22466622.38,13519219.09,-747.65,-1602.10,2568.93,-3251.94,5.72,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*2A
$PSTMTS,1,26,3381954.688,-49146.08,00,18,53036,1,-8037289.25,15873771.62,19660297.47,-1174.67,-2217.50,1326.00,26300.98,7.53,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*3C
$PSTMTS,1,22,3609068.188,-49215.92,00,21,27316,1,10235851.56,24348322.31,-2780494.62,-516.89,-162.93,-3068.35,-184537.24,7.77,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*08
$PSTMTS,1,27,5418358.750,-44043.68,00,19,77495,1,-10438473.00,23018353.00,-7765070.44,-768.74,651.32,3023.75,-13120.58,14.66,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*23
$PSTMTS,1,07,90050798.438,-44830.90,01,27,76584,1,25565687.72,6701073.97,4735275.25,-590.77,171.17,3061.98,17221.07,16.12,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*04
$PSTMTS,1,08,454836.875,-43869.36,00,20,3383,0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,0.00,0.00,0,0,0,0*2B
$PSTMNOTCHSTATUS,3786017,0,2449,0,2,5420680,0,3824,0,2*57
$PSTMADCDATA,943,903,,,,,,*48
$PSTMANTENNASTATUS,0*4D
$PSTMSBAS,0,0,,,,*19
$PSTMCPU,48.64,-1,49*41
```

Any help/ suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks [clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168986/clifford) for your suggestions. I need to parse data from RMC, VTG, GGA AND GSA. I am unable to change the baud rate and also being unable to stop proprietary sentences.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What is "wrong" about the VTG (Track made good and speed over ground) sentence?  There are other sentences in the stream; are they also "wrong".  It is normal to filter the stream to utilise only those sentences you need - what is wrong with simply discarding them?  The `GN` talker ID relates to a "hybrid" solution using more than one GNSS system (GPS + GLONASS for example).  It is not clear why only some of the sentences use the `GN` talker ID.  It may also possible to set a filter in the GNSS module itself so that only the required sentences are output.

Comment: Interesting that Quectel's proprietary sentences have ST Microelectronics' manufacturer ID - they clearly have not done any work beyond ST's reference implementation?

Comment: An NMEA 0183 sentence may also be no longer then 78 characters plus CR/LF, so these proprietary sentences are non-compliant, and make selection of an appropriate line buffer size difficult.

Comment: You can use this NMEA 0183 parser library for the embedded systems instead (it will ignore any proprietary sentences https://github.com/kosma/minmea

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing "wrong" about the output from your GNSS; it is normal for such a device to output a number of standard and proprietary sentences.  It is your responsibility to either configure the module to output only the sentences you need or parse the sentences and discard those you don't want.

Send the following command to the GNSS to disable all configurable sentences but the RMC sentence:

```
$PSMTSETPAR,1201,0X00000040*75
```

You need to either send this configuration every time on start-up, or save the configuration in the non-volatile memory by:

```
$PSMTSAVEPAR*58
```

It is possible that the module will output other sentences that are not configurable (I am not familiare with the specific module); you may still need to perform parsing and filtering on the host.  That is as simple as parsing the talker ID and format specifier and discarding sentences you are not interested in.  There are nay number of ways to do that; your question shows no such attempt.

Your code is too "low-level" as it is - the IEC61162-1 (NMEA 0183) sentence format is line oriented, but `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` will just grab a chunk of data without any knowledge of the protocol and entirely asynchronous to the sentence structure - you could as easily start and end mid-sentence.  Moreover `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` occurs in the interrupt context - that is not the place to be receiving large chunks of data and parsing it.  You first need some higher-level serial I/O code that will buffer the incoming data into a queue and support line-oriented input.

You then need to process each line - discarding those that are of no interest. In that sense it is too broad a question and not specifically related to GNSS data parsing - that is not really your problem here, it is as I say lower-level than than - you need ot build a suitable serial I/O infrastructure.

Another issue is that of you wait for 2400 characters to be received, you will get the data in chunks, and only the most recently received will be valid.  If real-time reception of current position is required; you cannot do it that way.

I am no ST HAL expert and would not choose to use it; it is poorly documented.  What it seems you should do in `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` is place the received data into a FIFO buffer that will be processed by some other thread (i.e. not in the interrupt context); because of variable length of NMEA sentences, you will need to do that on a single character basis.  A perhaps simpler method is to poll the HALL receive buffer with a zero timeout and accumulate characters until a line is available.  You can then inspect that line to see if it is an RMC sentence and then process that.  For example, the following allows non-blocking processing of serial input.  If no other functions need be performed, the timeout can be extended to wait indefinitely for each character:

```
// Strictly NMEA0183 requires only 81 byte sentence buffer, but 
// L89 appears to output non-compliant proprietary sentences.
static char line_buffer[1024];
int line_buffer_index = 0;

for (;;)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef rx_status = HAL_OK ;
    while( rx_status == HAL_OK )
    {
        // Receive a character if available (zero timeout)
        char ch = 0;
        HAL_StatusTypeDef rx_status = HAL_UART_Receive( &huart2, ch, 1, 0 ) ;

        // If character received and not the LF following the previous CR
        if( rx_status == HAL_OK && ch != `\n ` )
        {
            // If the end of the sentence...
            if( ch == `\r ` )
            {
                // terminate the line
                line_buffer[line_buffer_index] = `\0` ;

                // Start a new line
                line_buffer_index = 0 ;

                // Check if line is an RMC from a GNSS
                if( line_buffer_index > 6 &&
                    memcmp( line_buffer, "$G", 2) == 0 &&
                    memcmp( &line_buffer[3], "RMC", 3) == 0 )
                {
                    // Process RMC
                    processRMC( line_buffer ) ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // add character to line buffer
                line_buffer[line_buffer_index] = ch ;
                line_buffer_index++ ;
                if( line_buffer_index > sizeof(line_buffer) - 1 )
                {
                    // Line too long, discard all
                    line_buffer_index = 0 ;
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    // do other work here if necessary
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Clifford for your valuable inputs. I am new to STM32 architecture. I know NMEA sentences of L89 has no problem. I tried firing commands to L89 module and there was no response. I want to call HAL_UART_RECEIVE_IT only when there is new data in UART RX. How can I accomplish this task.

Comment: @ChandanKumar : As I commented, your question remains unclear, and your comment does nothing to clarify as it appears to be a different question.  Fix the question by editing it rather than further comment.  I'd be concerned in the first instance that you cannot configure the module.  The command I suggested was from documentation I found online, it may not be correct for your part.  You have overcomplicated your question by emphasising the role of the GNSS module when it is perhaps, just a simple question of CubeMX seria I/O.

Comment: Unless you use HAL_UART_Receive_IT with a buffer length of 1 (an interrupt per character), then it is probably unsuited to this application with variable length time sensitive data. It outputs an RMC every second; it will take several tens of seconds to accumulate 2400 characters that you are requesting.  Either way you need to do something with the data; you cannot reasonably deal with it in the Rx callback in the interrupt context.  My outline solution aims to simplify that; a more sophisticated solution is possible, but your current code is too far from that to suggest a solution.

Comment: Note also, being new to STM32 architecture is not the issue here. The HAL as it's name suggests is intended to isolate you from that.  I can't really help you with the HAL.  I have been using STM32 since long before ST introduced the frankly horrible CubeMX framework, and have my own solution.